# javascript authenticate with htpasswd and fetch json

Tags: javascript, .htpasswd

I have an API that generates json, problem is its password protected url, using Apache htpasswd.

how can I authenticate and retrieve the json from javascript, since all methods I have tried give me access deined (I've been using http://username:passwd@urldotcom/path/to/stuff)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to do it.

```
 var something = jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    username: "user",
    password: "password"    
});
```

url is a variable I declared earlier of format http:///path/to/json

Comment: do you think that this technique, or a similar one, could give access to htpasswd protected files? I have asked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65225037/how-can-client-side-javascript-send-a-user-id-password-to-an-apache-server-so-th).